# Curve object in liquid under pressure

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-statics

I would like to know how red forces are compensate in this study. A black solid object is put in a liquid (helium or hydrogen for example). It's a curved solid. Solid don't move up or down, imagine it like same density than liquid. I study translation at right or at left. Gravity is perpendicular to the screen.

Like study a liquid is difficult because forces are very small and there are a lot of problems: temperature, atomic effect, etc. I study with balls.

If I look details of atoms of liquid, they place like a part of circle (like the curvature of the solid). But like atoms pressure atoms at left or at right (in all directions), a red force will appear. This force decrease force to right. How pressure equilibrate red forces ?

[image]

---

Blue color is balls. Front: move up the top layer of balls and move down bottom layer of balls, balls let the black object move to the right. Rear: move down top layer of balls and move up bottom layer of balls. Like object is symmetric the energy to move balls is 0. Object has always the red force on it.

[image]

[image]

The container must block balls :

[image]

---

maybe with torque it's easier to see the problem ?

[image]

Not necessary balls are compressible. There is a net momentum on walls. Balls don't move in the shape.

Comment: Hey Ludovic, atoms are not balls.

Comment: I know but with atoms there are a lot of problem: temperature, quantic, etc and forces are so small... With balls I can thinking only with mechanical forces (no others parameters). I can understand with balls I need to give energy for compress ball when I move object in it but this energy can be recovered. That I don't understand it's the difference of pressure on the black object. I'm sure there is a net force on the black object. Why it can't move and give energy ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sum of energy with liquid and curved surface](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83370/)

Answer (score 1):

I think I see what you are getting at here. If the balls are in a state of compression, or suppose we replace them with point charges with some sort of repulsive Yukawa or Coulomb force, then there will indeed be a net force as you indicated (in red). There is nothing to equilibrate here because the balls would simply move away from eachother until they are far enough from each other that they simply bounce around as balls are known to do.

What you are describing is not a liquid but a gas (which can still behave like a a fluid). Now if you replace the purely repulsive forces by something like a Van der Waals interaction, it might be more realistic.

Anyway, the resolution to what I think your question is, is to consider not just these balls in isolation but in the context of all the balls in the container. The balls near the curved surface are held there in place by the next layer, and so on, until we reach the opposite boundary of the container.

Note that there is another contribution to the force (indicated in red), i.e., the reaction force from the solid indicated in black.

What you have arrived at is the observation that the pressure acting against the boundary of a fluid exerts a force normal to that boundary.

Comment: This reminds me of the analysis of surface tension.

Comment: I'm happy to see someone can understand my problem :) thanks ! In my last image balls move perpendicularly to the red force (no need energy), and black solid move in the direction of red force.

Answer (score 0):

There is no net load with hydrostatic pressure, unless there is a pressure gradient in one direction (like under gravity, $\frac{{\rm d}P}{{\rm d}y} = \rho g$). This is a result of [Divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) theorem and the balance of forces.

See these MIT lecture notes if you want to understand more (or you can look up hydrostatics yourself)

- http://web.mit.edu/~lianaiad/Public/OCW/Lec%203%20v1.pdf

The divergence theorem takes the dependency on the shape out of the balance of forces. It does not matter if the immersed solid is half moon shaped, triangle shaped, bunny shaped, potato shaped. The shape is is calceled out as the integral of surface force $\iint_{S}  \bf{n}\cdot P\,{\rm d}A$ over the entire surface is added up.

Comment: Could you explain where in your link the shape (and volume) of particles is in equations ? a/ and c/ of (first lines) is the main problem of my study. I know it's difficult to compute but not impossible. It's not a baby study.

Comment: In a closed curve, integrate the normal vector times a constant pressure over the entire curve and the result is going to be zero regarless of the shape of the curve.

Comment: but balls interact with each others, this change the force on object

Comment: Given the orders of magnitude difference is sizes, the "balls" or molecules do not see any curvature, not more than you can see the curvature of the earth when you stand up. You cannot model the solid as a smooth surface and the fuild as discrete particles. It is either both are discrete or both are smooth.

Comment: I done calculation here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/83370/sum-of-energy-with-liquid-and-curved-surface there is a net force

Comment: And when $\frac{r}{R} \approx 10^{-14}$ then the force is $\left(\frac{r}{R}\right)^2 \approx 10^{-37}$ which is all of a result of treating the solid surface as smooth and the fluid as balls. The solid surface has molecules too you know.

Comment: sure, but this force is not so small with macroscopic balls, take a solid of 1 m with 11 balls around the curve the force is big enough for moving object. If force of pressure is 100 N the red force is around 9 N.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11468/discussion-between-ludovic-and-ja72)

Comment: maybe you consider in 2D the system will block itself with balls, but with pressure from gravity for example, it's possible front balls move up and rear ball move down. Like that all the configuration of ball is the same everywhere around the black solid. If friction is at 0, there is a net force on black object.

Comment: Congrats you have just invented that small bubbles from a pint of Guiness migrate downwards when bigger bubbles move up.